# How to see test error messages on TFS Hosted

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild

My project is running in TFS Online (visualstudio.com) and at one moment a bunch of tests failed on TFS. Usually in such situations it was possible to reproduce the fail on my local machine, see the errors and fix them. (Well, almost always it just never got to server because of the 'run tests on build' feature).

But this time all the tests work fine on my machine, but some of them fail on TFS. And I need to see the errors of my tests on the server. But it seems there're no place in UI of hosted TFS to show that errors.

Here's what I can see:
«98/110 test(s) passed, 12 failed, 0 inconclusive» and the list of the failed tests: «Failed Given_VocabularyGrownEnough_When_AnalyzeGoals_Then_GoalsAchievedAndLessonEnded, Failed When_AnalyzeGoalsAndVocabularyGrownNotEnough_Then_Nothing, ...»

**Does anyone know how to dig somewhere into TFS hosted and get the test logs or at least the Assert's error messages?**

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

This is a great question.  Team Foundation Server nor VS Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online or Team Foundation Service) displays these often important exception or assert messages within failed tests *in the browser*.

[image: Browser Build Summary]

Within Visual Studio 2012/2013 you get test result messages.

[image: VisualStudio Build Summary]

## Visual Studio 2015

In Visual Studio 2015 they have taken away the Build Summary within Visual Studio and now when double clicking a build result in Team Explorer the summary will be opened in a browser.  It appears at first glance you can't see the actual test failure message but it is available under TEST -> Runs -> (double click failed test) -> Run Summary -> Test Results.

[image]

Comment: for VS 2015, the error message is truncated. Any chance you know how to see the entire error message?

Comment: @WesternAussie I'm pretty sure you can download the full logs and get the non-truncated error message.  A truncated error message is hopefully an oversight they address because the web-only view is already a step backwards IMHO.

Comment: I could not find the logs. Would you be able to point out where I can get them? Thanks!

Comment: @WesternAussie With an up-to-date TFS 2015 installation you can download the logs as a zip directly from Team Web Access' builds page. Just choose the build with the failed test and there's a command at the top to download all the logs as zip.  Also, with VS2015 Update 2, you can access these via a prior build summary in the builds page of the Team Explorer pane. It will be at the top under the "View Summary" heading with all the hyperlinks.